# Как преобразовать одну операцию в цикл для всех записей в таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица `PHOTO`. В этой таблице 3 столбца: `id, MYFILE (blob), ex_id`. Я написал сценарий, который позволил бы захватить фотографию с другой базы в столбец снимков в формате Base64 и записать ответ JSON. Но я не могу отладить этот скрипт вообще.

Mогу ли я отредактировать его, чтобы сделать все фотографии в цикле?

Этот скрипт работает только для одной записи (`where id = 196041;`):

```sql
Declare     
v_clob_post     CLOB;
v_clob          CLOB;
l_body_b        BLOB;
g_EXTERNAL_ID  varchar2(300);   
v_count int;
BEGIN 
select MYFILE INTO l_body_b from PHOTO  where id = 196041;
    apex_json.initialize_clob_output;
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('snapshot', blob_to_clob_base64(l_body_b)); 
    apex_json.close_object;
    V_clob  := apex_json.get_clob_output;
    apex_json.free_output;



                    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';  
                    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';  
                    v_clob_post  := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'myURL',p_http_method => 'POST'
                    ,p_body =>  v_clob );
 apex_json.parse(v_clob_post);     
 g_EXTERNAL_ID := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'id_document'); -- Obtain access_token
update PHOTO set EXTERNAL_ID = g_EXTERNAL_ID where id = 196041;
end;
```

Я хочу сделать это для всей таблицы в цикле, чтобы сделать все фотографии одновременно.

Answer (score 2):

Для обработкки всех записей достаточно цикла с неявным курсором:

```sql
create table photo (id number, value blob, extid varchar2 (128));
insert into photo 
    select rownum, empty_blob(), null from xmlTable ('1 to 3'); 

declare rowcount number := 0;
begin
    for r in (
        select * 
        from photo) loop
        /*** здесь вся логика обработки каждой фотографии из вопроса 
         ***/
        update photo p set extid = 'new external id here' 
        where p.id = r.id;
        rowcount := rowcount + sql%rowcount;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line (rowcount||' photos processed.'); 
end;
/

3 photos processed.
```